# Magit - rename last commit

Tags: git, magit

How do I rename the last commit in Magit (ie. edit the commit message) ?

I can see it in `magit-log-buffer-file`, but I don't know how to interact with it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Press <kbd>c</kbd> (*Commit*), then <kbd>a</kbd> (*Amend*), edit the message, <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>, profit!

Answer (score 11):

There is a command called `magit-commit-reword` in latest Magit(Current version:v2.13.0)

Steps:

1. Press `c` (Commit) at commit. (I usually move cursor to the first line after typing `magit-status` command)
2. Press `w` (Reword)
3. Rename
4. Press `C-c C-c` to commit
5. Done

Magit manual can be found here: https://magit.vc/manual/magit.html (Search reword in the page)

> c w     (magit-commit-reword)
>
> Reword the last commit, ignoring staged changes. With a prefix argument
>   keep the committer date, otherwise change it. The option
>   magit-commit-reword-override-date can be used to inverse the meaning
>   of the prefix argument.